# I can not delete data and i have error from adobe flash builder

Tags: sqlite, flash, actionscript, builder

I tried to make sqlite delete data process from adobe flash builder 4.6 but i can not success.i have below error.Other codes and things ok.i use datagrid component.The last code that i edited below:

protected function buton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void

```
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            function seckayit():void{
                var sec:SQLStatement=new SQLStatement;
                sec.sqlConnection=conn;
                sec.text="SELECT * FROM deneme";
                sec.execute();
                sec.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT,silkayit);
                function silkayit(event:SQLResult):void{
                stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                stmt.text="";
                //contactList.removeAll();
                stmt.text="DELETE FROM deneme WHERE id='"+liste.selectedItem.id+"'";            

                stmt.execute();

                }

            }
        }
```

and my mxml code is:

```
<s:Button x="206" y="-2" label="Kayıt Sil" click="silkayit(event)"/>
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at views::listviewHomeView/silkayit()[C:\Users\mobil-developer\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\veri-islem\src\sec.as:68]
    at views::listviewHomeView/___listviewHomeView_Button1_click()[C:\Users\mobil-developer\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\veri-islem\src\views\listviewHomeView.mxml:16]
```

where did i make mistake?What must i do? Would you like to help me?

Comment: Start the debugger and step through your program line by line

Comment: İ debugged this app but i can not solve this problem

Comment: Well, what line is on line 68 ? That is where this null exception occurs. Basically there are only two options: stmt is null or stmt.getResult() returns null. And what is data.id ? data is an Array, how does it have an id?

Comment: i have edited  code that i wrote. the list is listview componenet.i think datagrid or list component are same this codes  almost that i edited.where is my error?i can not delete datas with this codes.